# Import emails from a string

Tags: php

I would like to let my users paste a string of emails into a text are and on submit import them into a db table.

It seem that the typical syntax for email and they way it is usually typed in TO field is:

```
"Fname Lname" <abc@email.com>, "Fname Lname" <abc@gmail.com>,
```

I suppose on submit I need to parse it through some loop. How do I detect the name/email pair break? Is there a way to also do some basic email validation?

---

UPDATE:

I realized that sometimes the string can be slightly off, like missing a name:

```
Fname Lname" <abc@email.com>, abc@gmail.com,
```

or even

```
<abc@email.com>, abc@gmail.com,
```

or even

```
abc@email.com, abc@gmail.com,
```

How to make it more robust and note break if a name is missing? The email should be there all the time! Otherwise it just needs to ignore an instance and move on to the next contact. But I guess I can do that validation after the array of contacts is created...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not good in `preg_match`, so I tried it in another way. If your string is always in this pattern, you can try something like this:

```
$str = '"Fname Lname" <abc@email.com>, "Fname Lname" <xyz@gmail.com>';

$pairs = explode( ",", $str );

foreach( $pairs as $pair ) {

  $pair = explode( "<", $pair );
  $pair['0'] = trim( str_replace( "\"", "", $pair['0'] ) );
  $pair['1'] = trim( rtrim( $pair['1'], ">" ) );

  print_r( $pair ); // Save it to database here
}
```

### Test Here

## EDIT:

*(Change in input string)*

```
$str = '"Fname Lname" <abc@email.com>, abc@gmail.com';

$pairs = explode( ",", $str );

foreach( $pairs as $pair ) {

  if( strpos($pair, '<') ) {

    $output = explode( "<", $pair );
    $output['0'] = trim( str_replace( "\"", "", $output['0'] ) );
    $output['1'] = trim( rtrim( $output['1'], ">" ) );

  } else {

    $output = array();
    $output['0'] = '';
    $output['1'] = $pair;

  }

  print_r($output); // Save it to database here
}
```

### Test Here

Comment: Wow, this is great. What happens is a string is missing a name, like: "Fname Lname" <abc@email.com>, abc@gmail.com,

Comment: @santa: Please look at my edited answer. I hope you can handle any change in input string now :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using [preg_match_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) and [for](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php):

**PHP Example**

```
<?php

$string = '"Fname Lname" <abc@email.com>, "Fname Lname" <abc@email.com>,';
preg_match_all('!"(.*?)"\s+<\s*(.*?)\s*>!', $string, $matches);
$arr = array();
for ($i=0; $i<count($matches[0]); $i++) {
  $arr[] = array(
    'name' => $matches[1][$i],
    'email' => $matches[2][$i],
  );
}

?>
```

**Output:**

```
print_r($arr);

Array (
  [0] => Array (
    [name] => Fname Lname
    [email] => abc@email.com
  )
  [1] => Array (
    [name] => Fname Lname
    [email] => abc@email.com
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following regular expression will create an array with both the names, and the emails in sub arrays, in the keys `[1]` and `[2]` respectively:

```php
<?php

$data = '"Fname Lname" <abc@email.com>, "Fname Lname" <abc@gmail.com>,';
preg_match_all('/\"(.*?)\"\s\<(.*?)\>/', $data, $arr, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
print_r($arr);

?>
```

As for email validation, in php 5.2 and up you can use [`filter_var($variable, FILTER_ID)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php); specifically:

```php
if (filter_var($email_string, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { 
    // do stuff
}
```

[Described here](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php#example-4686).

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match("/<[a-zA-Z0-9\\-_\\.]@[a-zA-Z0-9\\-]\\.([a-z]{3})(\\.[a-z]{2})>/i", "", $emails);
```

Greetings,